# ContourPlot3D gives empty PlotLegends with Sqrt

Tags: plotting

I met a problem with `ContourPlot3D[]`. If I do this plot,

```
ContourPlot3D[Sqrt[(Sin[k1]^2 + Sin[k2]^2 + Sin[k3]^2) + (Cos[k1] + 
    Cos[k2] + Cos[k3] - 
    2)^2], {k1, -π, π}, {k2, -π, π}, {k3, -π, \
π}, AxesLabel -> {"k1", "k2", "k3"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

the legend is empty as in the image below

[image]

If I remove the outermost `Sqrt[]`, then the legend has actual values. I'm wondering how to make it work with the `Sqrt[]`. Thank you.

Comment: try `N@Sqrt[...]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks this actually works. It still puzzles me why `N@` is needed though.

Comment: My wild guess is that it has something to do with using exact values for the parameter ranges and `Sqrt` trying to evaluate to exact values. Using `N@Sqrt[stuff]` or `Sqrt[1. stufff]` or changing one of the `Pi`s  to `1. Pi` (or to `N@Pi`) gives the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

I don't know why the automatic legends don't work; however, the shown contours correspond to `{2, 3, 4}`

The range of the function is

```
#[{
    Sqrt[(Sin[k1]^2 + Sin[k2]^2 + 
        Sin[k3]^2) + (Cos[k1] + Cos[k2] + Cos[k3] - 2)^2],
    -Pi < k1 < Pi, -Pi < k2 < Pi, -Pi < k3 < Pi},
   {k1, k2, k3}] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue}

(* {1., 5.} *)
```

Choosing the intermediate integer values and explicitly specifying the legend values

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Sqrt[(Sin[k1]^2 + Sin[k2]^2 + 
     Sin[k3]^2) + (Cos[k1] + Cos[k2] + Cos[k3] - 
      2)^2], {k1, -π, π}, {k2, -π, π}, {k3, -π, π},
 Contours -> {2, 3, 4},
 AxesLabel -> {"k1", "k2", "k3"},
 PlotLegends -> {2, 3, 4}]
```

[image]

**Reported to Wolfram Tech Support (Case 5055163)**

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `Sqrt` with [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html):

```
ContourPlot3D[N @ 
 Sqrt[(Sin[k1]^2 + Sin[k2]^2 + Sin[k3]^2) + (Cos[k1] + Cos[k2] + Cos[k3]-2)^2],
 {k1, -π, π}, {k2, -π, π}, {k3, -π, π},
 AxesLabel -> {"k1", "k2", "k3"},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can replace `Sqrt[stuff]` with  `Sqrt[N @ stuff]` or replace any of the `π`s in domain specs with `N @ π` to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

[image: contour plot]

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Sqrt[(Sin[k1]^2 + Sin[k2]^2 + 
     Sin[k3]^2) + (Cos[k1] + Cos[k2] + Cos[k3] - 
      2)^2], {k1, -π, π}, {k2, -π, π}, {k3, -π, \
π}, AxesLabel -> {"k1", "k2", "k3"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"k1=7", "k2=13", "k3=19"}]
```

Change PlotLegends, you will get your answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for automatically computed legends and understanding why this happens. Thanks.